# How to redirect to intended page with authentication guard in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

#### Background

I am  using the [ldaprecord-laravel](https://github.com/DirectoryTree/LdapRecord-Laravel) package for LDAP authentication with Laravel 8. Users will be asked to authenticate to reach their intended page, and should be redirected to the intended page after authenticating. Basic authentication redirects correctly, but after I add my custom authentication guard a valid login will redirect to the home page of the application (RouteServiceProvider::HOME), which is the default behavior.

#### What I have tried

I tried editing `App/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` to redirect to the intended page instead of the home page, I get the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` as it continually redirects from login -> intended -> login -> intended -> (...).

```
// App/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);  
                // Original: return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

I have made no changes to Fortify's default routing behavior. Is there another way to redirect Fortify authentication when using a guard, or a missing configuration somewhere?